# Change background image of elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I want to change the background images of the body, header, menu and main blocks of my page on link click. First, I'm trying change only body background. My default body background image is assigned in my CSS file:

```
html, body {
    height:1100px;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 1150px;
    background-image: url(../Unnamed%20Site%202/ff%20copy7.jpg);
}
```

I tried this jQuery function but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="Your name" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Electrolize'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div id="home">
               <div class="menu">
                   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
                   <script>
                   $("#home").click(function() { 
                       $("body").css("backgroundImage", "url(sandpaper.png)");
                   });
                   </script>

     ...Some text into main (box)...
             </div>
         </div>
         ...
```

Comment: `$("body").css("background-image", "url(sandpaper.png)");`

Comment: @Morpheus : feel free to put it as answer because it's an answer

Comment: my fault, thanks but it not solve the problem

Comment: @Morpheus [That doesn't matter to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2).

Comment: Have you read the article you have posted yourself?

Comment: Are you sure the image can be found? Try using a URL for the image that's relative to the root directory: `url(/images/sandpaper.png)`

Comment: yes i tried it with ("background-color", "#000000"); . It work only when i use $(document).ready(function() {  but i must double click for change background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be:

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url('sandpaper.png')");
```

Also, might I suggest using the `.addClass()` `.removeClass()` or `.toggleClass` functions instead? They offer a cleaner solution.

Comment: I used .addClass and now it work perfect. Thank you. But it do not work in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Set the event-function after the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').click(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', "url('sandpaper.png')");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank with $(document).ready(function() { it work , but i must doble click on link for change background. You do not know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you have to click it two times. What I do recommend however, is to declare your `<script>` tags in either the `<head>` or at the bottom of your HTML.

Comment: I tried it. I click on link (background is still default) and after it i must click everywhere on site for change background .

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$("body").css("backgroundImage", "url(sandpaper.png)");
```

to:

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url(sandpaper.png)");
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

`$("body").css("background-image", "url(sandpaper.png)");`

Or if you want to do your way:

```
$("body").css({
   backgroundImage: "url(sandpaper.png)"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to change :

```
$("body").css("backgroundImage", "url(sandpaper.png)");
```

To:

```
 $("body").css("background-image", "url(sandpaper.png)");
```

Comment: it do not help to me . It does not change background.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help. I solved it.
I created in my **css** file BG class:

```
.bg1 { background: url(sandpaper.png) repeat-x; }
```

And i used **jquery** script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("#link-home").click( function(){ $
        ("body").addClass("bg1");
    });
```